# SCIP failing on an MIP problem when calling from Julia/JuMP

Tags: scip, julia-jump

I am new to SCIP and JuMP.  I just installed SCIP in VS Code, and I can successfully use it to solve an optimization problem if I formulate it directly in Julia/JuMP.

However, when trying to read an existing small MIP problem from .mps file, I get the error below. Note that I can solve the same problem easily if I switch set_optimizer to GLPK or Gurobi.

```
using JuMP
using GLPK
using Gurobi
using SCIP

model = read_from_file("smallMIP.mps")
set_optimizer(model, SCIP.Optimizer)
optimize!(model)
```

Thank you for your help.

---

Error:

presolving:
(round 1, fast)       475 del vars, 21 del conss, 0 add conss, 21 chg bounds, 0 chg sides, 0 chg coeffs, 0 upgd conss, 0 impls, 234 clqs
(round 2, fast)       938 del vars, 119 del conss, 0 add conss, 21 chg bounds, 0 chg sides, 0 chg coeffs, 0 upgd conss, 0 impls, 224 clqs
(round 3, exhaustive) 938 del vars, 121 del conss, 0 add conss, 21 chg bounds, 0 chg sides, 0 chg coeffs, 0 upgd conss, 0 impls, 224 clqs
(round 4, exhaustive) 938 del vars, 121 del conss, 0 add conss, 21 chg bounds, 0 chg sides, 0 chg coeffs, 224 upgd conss, 0 impls, 224 clqs
(0.0s) probing cycle finished: starting next cycle
(round 5, exhaustive) 942 del vars, 121 del conss, 0 add conss, 21 chg bounds, 0 chg sides, 0 chg coeffs, 224 upgd conss, 0 impls, 1805 clqs
(round 6, fast)       942 del vars, 129 del conss, 0 add conss, 21 chg bounds, 0 chg sides, 0 chg coeffs, 224 upgd conss, 0 impls, 1805 clqs
(0.0s) probing: 122/241 (50.6%) - 0 fixings, 4 aggregations, 1663 implications, 0 bound changes
(0.0s) probing aborted: 50/50 successive totally useless probings
(0.0s) symmetry computation started: requiring (bin +, int -, cont +), (fixed: bin -, int +, cont -)
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _*ZN5bliss13AbstractGraph18find_automorphismsERNS_5StatsEPFvPvjPKjES3*
Referenced from: /Users/dudley/.julia/artifacts/61cc42a9d4c8873fe13702e847ac81ef672d40c5/lib/libscip.7.0.dylib
Expected in: /Users/dudley/.julia/artifacts/e8e14099d396b38630b2555b46448e3e1c7c476a/lib/libbliss.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: _*ZN5bliss13AbstractGraph18find_automorphismsERNS_5StatsEPFvPvjPKjES3*
Referenced from: /Users/dudley/.julia/artifacts/61cc42a9d4c8873fe13702e847ac81ef672d40c5/lib/libscip.7.0.dylib
Expected in: /Users/dudley/.julia/artifacts/e8e14099d396b38630b2555b46448e3e1c7c476a/lib/libbliss.dylib

signal (6): Abort trap: 6
in expression starting at /Users/dudley/Documents/Julia/test2.jl:30
strsignal at /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib (unknown line)
jl_critical_error at /Applications/Julia-1.7.app/Contents/Resources/julia/lib/julia/libjulia-internal.1.7.dylib (unknown line)
sigdie_handler at /Applications/Julia-1.7.app/Contents/Resources/julia/lib/julia/libjulia-internal.1.7.dylib (unknown line)
_sigtramp at /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib (unknown line)
unknown function (ip: 0x0)
Allocations: 34026932 (Pool: 34018136; Big: 8796); GC: 34
(0.1s) symmetry computation started: requiring (bin +, int -, cont +), (fixed: bin -, int +, cont -)
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _*ZN5bliss13AbstractGraph18find_automorphismsERNS_5StatsEPFvPvjPKjES3*
Referenced from: /Users/dudley/.julia/artifacts/61cc42a9d4c8873fe13702e847ac81ef672d40c5/lib/libscip.7.0.dylib
Expected in: /Users/dudley/.julia/artifacts/e8e14099d396b38630b2555b46448e3e1c7c476a/lib/libbliss.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: _*ZN5bliss13AbstractGraph18find_automorphismsERNS_5StatsEPFvPvjPKjES3*
Referenced from: /Users/dudley/.julia/artifacts/61cc42a9d4c8873fe13702e847ac81ef672d40c5/lib/libscip.7.0.dylib
Expected in: /Users/dudley/.julia/artifacts/e8e14099d396b38630b2555b46448e3e1c7c476a/lib/libbliss.dylib
*

Answer (score 0):

Please open an issue in SCIP.jl: https://github.com/scipopt/SCIP.jl

Before doing so, make sure you have updated your packages: `import Pkg; Pkg.update()`.

And be sure to include `versioninfo()` and `import Pkg; Pkg.status()` in your post.